# TypeORM Insert Cascade no effect

Tags: typescript, typeorm, nest, cascade

I Have a parent entity `CostCenter` that contains an Array of `Coordinators`,
`coordinators: Array<Coordinator>` and this attribute has the typeORM annotations as follows

```
export class CostCenter {
...
@OneToMany(() => Coordinator, (coordinator) => coordinator.costCenter, {
    eager: true,
    cascade: ['insert', 'update'],
  })
  coordinators: Array<Coordinator>;
...
}
```

And my coordinator is as follows:

```
export class Coordinator {
...
  @ManyToOne(() => CostCenter, (costCenter) => costCenter.coordinators, {
    cascade: ['insert', 'update'],
  })
  costCenter: CostCenter;
...
}
```

And I am trying to save a CostCenter that contains the array of coordinators:

```
async create(createCostCenterDto: CreateCostCenterDto) {
    const costCenter = new CostCenter(
      createCostCenterDto.code,
      createCostCenterDto.description,
      createCostCenterDto.id,
    );

    var coordinators = new Array<Coordinator>();
    await createCostCenterDto.coordinators.forEach((coordinator) => {
      coordinators.push(
        new Coordinator(
          coordinator.name,
          coordinator.email,
          coordinator.password,
          coordinator.id,
          coordinator.telephone,
          coordinator.registration,
          coordinator.course,
          coordinator.graduation,
        ),
      );
      this.coordinatorRepository.save(coordinator);
    });

    costCenter.coordinators = coordinators;
    return this.costCentersRepository.insert(costCenter);
  }
```

Following the instructions of the typeORM(https://typeorm.io/#/relations/cascades) documentation this code should work, however this code is saving both entities and the coordinator that should contain the foreing key of costCenter does not receive it.
I also tried commenting the line: `this.coordinatorRepository.save(coordinator);` after commenting it, the cascade did not work at all, it saves the costCenter but not the coordinators.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: What is the actual database being used?

Comment: The line where it says `return this.costCentersRepository.insert(costCenter);` I changed to `.save()` for some reason with save it works, but did not work for me with insert

Answer (score 3):

TypeORM makes a distinction between low level methods that implement the main SQL keywords vs more higher level functions which also trigger cascade.

The case being that save unlike insert triggers cascade.

From the docs:

> /**
> * Inserts a given entity into the database. 
> * Unlike save method executes a primitive operation without cascades, relations and other operations included. 
> * Executes fast and efficient INSERT query. 
> * Does not check if entity exist in the database, so query will fail if duplicate entity is being inserted. 
> */ 
> insert(entity: QueryDeepPartialEntity | (QueryDeepPartialEntity[])): Promise;

A similar distinction exists between the repository's remove and delete methods.

In your case, since you are trying to cascade insert coordinators when inserting a new CostCenter into the database you should use the repository's .save() method rather than .insert().

Comment: You'r points are helpful, but to make this a more a solution rather than an explanation you could  highlight that changing `.insert()` to `.save()` triggers cascade.